# How to convert a video NSURL to an ALAsset?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, alasset, fbsdk

Facebook sharing requires an ALAsset such as the following:

```
let content = FBSDKShareVideoContent()

//The videos must be less than 12MB in size.

let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.URLForResource("a", withExtension: "mp4")

let video = FBSDKShareVideo()
// doesn't work; needs to be an "asset url" (ALAsset)
//video.videoURL = path

content.video = video

let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
dialog.shareContent = content
dialog.show()
```

How is it possible to take a local bundle document, or an NSData object, and convert it to an ALAsset?

(My initial thinking was saving the video to the local camera roll, and then loading the list and selecting it, but that is unnecessary interface steps)

Comment: after a quick look in the documentation , I can see that in iOS 9 ALAsset is deprecated , the new object is PHAsset https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHAsset/fetchAssetsWithMediaType:options:

Comment: But Facebook still requires it, and I'm not sure the current SDK supports PHAsset.  I also need to get this to work in iOS 8.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/index.html) for an ALAsset states that

> An ALAsset object represents a photo or a video managed by the Photo application.

so I'm pretty sure that you have to write the video to the camera roll before using it as an **ALAsset**. However, you don't need to open the camera roll and have a user pick the asset in order to use it. When writing to the **ALAssetLibrary** using

```
library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(movieURL, completionBlock: { (newURL, error) -> Void
```

you get the asset url in that **newUrl** completion block variable. Use it in the Facebook sharing call

```
let content = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
content.video = FBSDKShareVideo(videoURL: newURL)

FBSDKShareAPI.shareWithContent(content, delegate: self)
NSLog("Facebook content shared \(content.video.videoURL)")
```

You can do this sharing inside the completion block if you so desire, or you can save the newUrl from the completion block and use it somewhere else.